# Pink chic skin in Fortnite

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

Can you still unlock the pink chic skin? I ak now in Chapter 2 Season 2. Is this still an unlockable skin?

Please help guys. I am going crazy

Answer (score 0):

No. It was a limited time style for Chapter 1 Season 1. It will not come back ever. You had to do challenges in season 11 to unlock it. Sorry you can't get it.